# Can I store a Lucene index in a database or other location than a file system?

Tags: c#, azure, lucene.net

I use Lucene.NET for my web project.  I wish to migrate the indexing to webjobs using Azure, however Lucene uses an traditional 'file system' to store the index.

Are there other options to stored and write to the index, such as SQL?

Comment: Better way is to get a VM and have permanent Disk drive. if you go for PaaS then you will face above problem. You can't put lucene index in SQL. It will murder it's purpose to be honest. As @astaykov has said you, azure directory is one of the option, but believe me it sucks in performance. I have used it previously then we switched to VM.

Comment: Can you try looking at elastic search? It internally uses Lucene only. One of the projects we actually moved to elastic search. Honestly I don't have in depth knowledge of the same. But it kind of provides you rest based APIs to access data in lucene index.

Comment: This project might interest you: https://github.com/MahyTim/LuceneNetSqlDirectory

Answer (score 2):

Azure Directory for Lucene.Net: 
https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureDirectory

A bit, and probably not well supported, but there is no another option that I am aware of. You cannot store Lucene data in DB (whatever DB). It just makes no sense.

Comment: I agree - however Lucene is 'file system' based which present challenges with cloud hosting or just fault tolerance in general.  Looking for any way to read and write to the index without old fashioned file systems.

Comment: then use abstraction layer on top of it - like Elastic Search or Solr. Elastic runs pretty well on Azure VMs.

Answer (score 2):

All I/O operations in Lucene is done through the [Directory](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) class. So if want to use a different storage engine for your index, all you need to do is implement a custom Directory. For an example of how to do this, have a look at this project: [MongoDB.Lucene](https://bitbucket.org/ludovicchabant/mongodb.lucene). Others have implemented it on top of Azure, Redis, etc.